# Oracle tutorial "Fancy Forms with JavaFX CSS" not working?

Tags: java, css, netbeans

So I did the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/css.htm#BABBGJBI) and everything went well, until i tried to run it. I didn't find a problem with the code and since it didn't work eventually just decided to directly copy the Oracle example project to the Netbeans projects directory, and im still having the same problem.

The project builds without errors nor warnings, but doesn't run and gives the kind of error message i don't have any clue about with my java skills.

So below is the full error message. The project can be downloaded [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/LoginCSS.zip). I just recently downloaded the newest versions of Netbeans and JDK so that should not be the problem. Please help me out here, is there an error in the tutorial or did i do something wrong?

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at      sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
```

`Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at login.Login.start(Login.java:101)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application login.Login
Java Result: 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a NullPointerException at this line of code:

```
    scene.getStylesheets().add(Login.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());
```

The code is ok. Did you somehow mess up the file names or paths? The css file does not seem to be found.

Comment: Wow that actually did it. I put the css file in the same directory as the java source file, and it worked. However, in the Oracle example project it was in the project main directory, so there probably was an error with the tutorial, since i followed all the steps in the tutorial and didn't mess up any file names or paths.

Comment: I downloaded the zip file from the link you gave above and there it is in the right place already. Anyway - I am glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: Youre right, i must have messed up at some point. I think i created a separate css file in the main directory or something. Anyway, thanks for the answer.